# Grand Tour USA (Helvetiq): How can you travel to Hawaii and Alaska?

Tags: house-rules

Players can typically move by passing through bordering states following correctly answering a question. Although there are chance cards which allow for travel via oceans, they seem too infrequent to be the only means of getting to the 2 non-contiguous states. I can't find anything in the rules to address this issue; anyone have a fix?

Comment: try their facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/helvetiq/